# Chrome App - Manual Update form within the app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a chrome application that might change over time. I discovered the option for *auto updating*, but I'm curious if there is an option to trigger *manual update* from within the app itself. I know there is an "Update extension now" button at *chrome://extensions* while *developer mode* enabled, but I'd like to notify user about new version directly in the app and give him nice and simple way to update.

I found a way to discover that a new version was released. Like so:

```
chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck( callback );
```

Maybe I missed the one, to perform such thing as update&restart.

Anyone? Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option for auto updating. If you don't add manual update checks, Chrome will still automatically update it.

You are probably looking for the [UpdateAvailable event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable).

"Fired when an update is available, but isn't installed immediately because the app is currently running. If you do nothing, the update will be installed the next time the background page gets unloaded, if you want it to be installed sooner you can explicitly call chrome.runtime.reload()"